# How to Trigger & Submit SAS job through LSF when receiving JMS Message on a Topic

Tags: sas, jms, jms-topic, lsf

I have to find out a mechanism to have the SAS Middle Tier hosting a JMS Listener subscribed to certain JMS Topic, and whenever a message appears on the JMS Topic the JMS Listener sitting on the SAS Middle Tier should trigger LSF to execute the SAS program.

Assuming the above flow I have few dots to connect.(Also a reference link/code or documentation on the same will help)

- How can a JMS Listener (sitting on SAS Middle Tier) invoke/trigger the LSF on arrival on any message on the JMS Topic.?

**Update**: I was able make the SMC(SAS Management Console) connect to the JMS Queue to send and receive messages to the SAS programs, but I still struggling how to configure the JMS Topic from SMC.

Anyone who would have configure this, any link or supporting docs will be helpful here.

Please let me know in case I need to elaborate more to explain the issue.
Thanks in advance